# Where do I go to learn to write raw MAPI commands for Exchange integration?

Tags: exchange-server, mapi, outlook-redemption

I've had a few headaches trying to use Outlook and Redemption in my VB .Net application. Is there a guide anywhere on the net that describes the MAPI protocol and how I might go about using it to interact with a connection to Exchange server?

I know that there's a serious risk of creating *more* headaches by trying this approach, but I'm interested none the less.

TIA,
Dave
--Trindaz on Fedang #MAPI-guide

Answer (score 1):

Don't use MAPI from .NET. It's not supported by Microsoft due to some collisions between the GC and MAPI internal memory management.

On the clientside, you can use the Outlook Object model, Redemption. On the server side, use Exchange WebServices for Exchange 2007/2010 and WebDAV or CdoEx for Exchange 2000/2003.